# Classical Mechanics by John R. Taylor Chapter 1 Problem 40

Tags: classical-mechanics

[image: This is a problem from Classical Mechanics by John R. Taylor Chapter 1 Problem 40]
This is a problem from Classical Mechanics by John R. Taylor Chapter 1 Problem 40
I got an answer of 70.5deg but I'm not sure if it is correct

Comment: I find the same result.

Comment: Thanks! I'm just confirming my results...